# Program received signal "EXC_Bad_Access" NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, objective-c, arrays, ios

if I try and reun the code below I get an EXE_bad_access message on [categoryList count]

```
NSMutableArray *categoryList = [[CategoryItem alloc] getAll];
NSLog(@"number of items is %@", [categoryList count]);
```

The class is below

```
#import "CategoryItem.h"

#import "SQLite.h"

@interface CategoryItem : NSObject {
    NSInteger ID;
    NSInteger SortOrder;
    NSString *Name;
    NSString *ShoppingImage;

}

@property (nonatomic, nonatomic) NSInteger SortOrder;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * Name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * ShoppingImage;
@property (nonatomic, nonatomic) NSInteger ID;

- (id)initWithObject:(NSInteger)itemID;
-(NSMutableArray *)getAll;

@end
@implementation CategoryItem


@synthesize ShoppingImage;
@synthesize Name;
@synthesize ID;
@synthesize SortOrder;

- (id)initWithObject:(NSInteger)itemID {

    if ((self = [super init])) {
        sqlite3 *database;
        // Open the database. The database was prepared outside the application.
        if (sqlite3_open([[SQLite fullFilePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
            // Get the primary key for all books.
            const char *sql = "SELECT ID, Name, ShoppingImage, SortOrder FROM CategoryItem WHERE ID =?";
            sqlite3_stmt *statement;
            // Preparing a statement compiles the SQL query into a byte-code program in the SQLite library.
            // The third parameter is either the length of the SQL string or -1 to read up to the first null terminator.        
            if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
                // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
                sqlite3_bind_int(statement, 1, itemID);

                while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW) {
                    // The second parameter indicates the column index into the result set.
                    self.ID = itemID;
                    self.Name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                    self.ShoppingImage = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                    self.SortOrder = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 3);
                }
            }
            // "Finalize" the statement - releases the resources associated with the statement.
            sqlite3_finalize(statement);
        } else {
            // Even though the open failed, call close to properly clean up resources.
            sqlite3_close(database);
            NSLog(@"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
            // Additional error handling, as appropriate...
        }

    }
    return self;
}

-(NSMutableArray*)getAll{

    NSMutableArray *listArray = [[[NSMutableArray alloc] init] autorelease];

    sqlite3 *database;
    // Open the database. The database was prepared outside the application.
    if (sqlite3_open([[SQLite fullFilePath] UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) {
        // Get the primary key for all books.
        const char *sql = "SELECT ID, Name, ShoppingImage, SortOrder FROM CategoryItem ORDER BY SortOrder";
        sqlite3_stmt *statement;
        // Preparing a statement compiles the SQL query into a byte-code program in the SQLite library.
        // The third parameter is either the length of the SQL string or -1 to read up to the first null terminator.

        if (sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &statement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) 
        {

            // We "step" through the results - once for each row.
            while (sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
            {
                // The second parameter indicates the column index into the result set.

                CategoryItem *categoryItem = [[CategoryItem alloc] init];

                categoryItem.ID = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 0);
                categoryItem.Name = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 1)];
                categoryItem.ShoppingImage = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 2)];
                categoryItem.SortOrder = sqlite3_column_int(statement, 3);

                [listArray addObject:categoryItem];

                [categoryItem release];
                categoryItem = nil;

            }


        }else{
            printf( "could not prepare statemnt: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database) ); 
        }
        // "Finalize" the statement - releases the resources associated with the statement.
        sqlite3_finalize(statement);

    } else {
        // Even though the open failed, call close to properly clean up resources.
        sqlite3_close(database);
        NSLog(@"Failed to open database with message '%s'.", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        // Additional error handling, as appropriate...
    }

    //NSLog(@"this is the list array count %@", [listArray count]);

    return listArray;
}



- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [Name release];
    [ShoppingImage release];

}


@end
```

Comment: Only masochists use the SQLite C API directly in Objective-C.  [Use FMDB](http://github.com/ccgus/fmdb) (a SQLite wrapper) or [CoreData](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) (an object graph manager) instead.

Comment: @Luke shouldn't you initialize that `CategoryItem`? You are calling `alloc` but not `initWithObject`...

Comment: You haven't initialized the class CategoryList, yet you call a method on it. Seems the problem is in the (non-existant) initialization.

Comment: Indeed, whenever you have to write that many comments to recall what is going on, that is a sign an abstraction layer could be highly beneficial.

Comment: Please try Core Data. Roughly same work to set up but so much easier to work with. If you do it right you can easily prepare a data set to ship with your app too ("The database was prepared outside the application.")

Comment: @albertamg yes but shouldn't CategoryItem *categoryItem = [[CategoryItem alloc] init]; create an empty instance of CategoryItem?

Comment: @Wolfgang Schreurs no CategoryList isn't the name of the class

Comment: Yes I think I might have to give Core Data ago again although I couldn't find a neat way to filled the data set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem right the way you create your `CategoryItem`. You are calling `alloc`but not any `init...` method. You may want to use the `initWithObject` method that you have provided in your implementation.

From [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH22-SW1):

> It takes two steps to create an object
>   using Objective-C. You must:
>
> - Dynamically allocate memory for the
>     new object
> - Initialize the newly
>     allocated memory to appropriate values
>
> An object isn’t fully functional until
>   both steps have been completed. Each
>   step is accomplished by a separate
>   method but typically in a single line
>   of code:
>
> id anObject = [[Rectangle alloc]
>   init];

**EDIT:**

Beyond the initialization problem, there seems to be a conceptual problem (pointed out by @Terry Wilcox):
Calling the method `getAll`on an instance does not seem to make sense and therefore should be defined as a class method instead:

```
+ (NSMutableArray*)getAll;
```

and should be called like this:

```
NSMutableArray *categoryList = [CategoryItem getAll];
```

**EDIT 2:**

Your log statement does not seem right either. `[categoryList count]`returns a `NSUInteger`and you are trying to print an object with `%@`. Use `%i`instead:

```
NSLog(@"number of items is %i", [categoryList count]);
```

Comment: The code isn't trying to create a CategoryItem, it's trying to create an NSMutableArray.

Comment: @Luke You are also trying to log an int as if it was an object (see EDIT 2)

Comment: omg it was the log statement it self. Thanks so much
I removed the log statement yesterday and it started working and didn't even think about it.
Oh well thats an hour of my life that I'll never get back

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
NSMutableArray *categoryList = [[CategoryItem alloc] getAll];
```

doesn't make sense. If getAll is a class method on CategoryItem, then it should be defined as

```
+ (NSMutableArray*)getAll;
```

and you should call it as

```
NSMutableArray *categoryList = [CategoryItem getAll];
```

Then categoryList will be an array that you don't own, so you may want to retain it when you get it.

Comment: thanks for that much cleaner code!still doesn't solve my memory issues though

Comment: It's not cleaner code, it's working code. Your original code wouldn't work properly, it's not calling init so your getAll method may not be returning anything.